# Visual Studio C vs. C++ Flag Issue

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, c++11

In Visual Studio, have things setup (using vs-android) to apply `-std=c++11` through the "Additional Options" in "Compiler Arguments" in the project.  Which is good, because it applies it to all compiled files.

Except when it tries to compile a C file:

> cc1.exe : warning : command line option '-std=c++11' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]

Which is just a warning, but it slows down the build ever so slightly every time, and there's a lot of pure C files.

Is there any way to make an exception for this in Visual Studio, so it isn't done to C files, but only C++ files?

Comment: Never tried it but I think I read that it's possible with CMake.

Comment: Is this one project, that has a mixture of C and C++ files? Ar the C files not compilable as C++?

Comment: I think the only solution, in that case, is to split the project - so you have one part of C files (with no `std=c++11`) and another project with C++ files (with `std=c++11`). Let one of the projects "depend" on the other, and make it produce either a .dll or a .lib, that the other links against.

Comment: @BobbyDigital I'd rather stick to using vs-android ;).

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes it is a mixture. The C files are compatible as C++, that isn't a concern. The separate project so isn't very trivial to do on Android (using vs-android).

Comment: What I meant is, can you just stick `extern "C" {` around the code in the .c files and compile it as C++?

Comment: @MatsPetersson The code already has that - it doesn't solve any issue.

Comment: Hang on, is this using `gcc` inside Visual studio? If so, I suspect the best way would be to simply rename the .c files to .cpp.

Comment: That would probably defeat the purpose, since they will then be treated as C++ which is a little slower to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, there's no way to do it in the manner you are looking for.

One thing that may work for you, depending on if you are using any other global command-line options or not, is select all of your .C files in the project, and in the compiler options un-check the "Inherit from parent or project defaults" checkbox just above the Additional Options box. You should be able to do it for all of your C files in one shot by ctrl-selecting them and then right-click/Properties/etc. Then any of the extra command-line options you set at the project level will not be used for those files.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't see that checkbox there.  That did it!